# SlidingTabLayout's tabs language are not changed after changing application resources language programmatically

Tags: java, android, localization, android-tabs

I am trying to add some fatures to a prebuilt android application and one of them is changing application language programmatically.

What I am doing to change app's resources is: executing this code in onCreate for each activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        android.content.res.Configuration conf  = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.setLocale(new Locale(Utils.getAppPreferences("LANG")));
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }

// static member functions to return the sharedpreference that holds app's current language
public static String getDeviceLanguage() {

    return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
}


public static String getAppPreferences(String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = AppController.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences", 0);
    return sharedpreferences.getString(key, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
}

 // and after all of this I am restarting MainActivity 
  Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I need to switch between arabic "ar" and english "en".
The translations are already available for all languages in resources. 
All of the resources are being changed ***except only TabBarLayout tabs still using device language.***

Answer (score 0):

Language has to be set before setting the content view. If that is not possible restart the activity through a new intent and finish the old activity.